# Django update template QuerySet data with Ajax

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have to update data on template with usage of Ajax and Django views.
In template have button that shell update table context based on view response.

I have read several similar responses: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875704/update-a-django-filefield-with-ajax), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687817/respond-to-ajax-with-django-template-rendered), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209023/django-template-with-jquery-ajax-update-on-existing-page), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103161/ajax-call-not-updating-template-django), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592702/render-page-with-model-after-ajax-post), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648780/how-to-redirect-to-new-pagealong-with-model-on-jquery-ajax-call-in-mvc3),  but can't find solution.

template.html

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning vindication" value="vindication">Vindication</button>

<table class="table" align="center">
    <thead class="black">
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="data">
        {% for client in invoices_all_data %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ client.data }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".vindication").click(function(){

            var vindication_type = $(this).attr("value");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/invoices/vindication_filter/",
                data: {
                    vindication_type : vindication_type,
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#data').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

After button click data is send to views.py function where is processed:

```
def vindication_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        vindication_type = request.POST['vindication_type']

        # filter data
        client_data = MonitoringUsers.objects.all()
        invoices_all_data = MonitoringUsers.objects.none()

        for client in client_data:
            if client.get_all_invoices():
                invoices_all_data = invoices_all_data | MonitoringUsers.objects.filter(
                    user_id=client.user_id, pay_status=vindication_type)


        return TemplateResponse(request, "template.html", locals())
```

To this point code is working but i con't figure how to return processed data [invoices_all_data - QuerySet] back into main template.html?

Thank You for any sugestions.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't return a `TemplateResponse` but a `JsonResponse` with the HTML on it as a string, something along the lines:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse


html_rendered = render_to_string('template.html', your_context_dictionary_here)
return JsonResponse({'html': html_rendered})
```

And then in the JavaScript just append the HTML wherever you want.

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#data').html(response['html']);
}
```

Comment: context is QuerySet. This approach will return invoices_all_data object into main template?

Comment: generally, when you render a template you send data from the Django view.

for example, in HTML:

<h1>hello {{name}}</h1>

the context in the view can be {"name":"Zaraki"}

Comment: if i use csrf_token in html form then i need to pass this token into view and back with additional data into template?

Comment: @Dalvtor Can one use render() instead of JsonResponse() after an ajax request? I cannot find any good source on that very topic, but it seems that JsonResponse() should be the way to go with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that your view is called via `ajax` you simply need to return your `invoices_all_data` by `return invoices_all_data` in your view. So in your `success` function in your `ajax` call the `response` variable you use is your `invoices_all_data`.

```
def vindication_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        vindication_type = request.POST['vindication_type']

        # filter data
        client_data = MonitoringUsers.objects.all()
        invoices_all_data = MonitoringUsers.objects.none()

        for client in client_data:
            if client.get_all_invoices():
                invoices_all_data = invoices_all_data | MonitoringUsers.objects.filter(
                    user_id=client.user_id, pay_status=vindication_type)


        return JsonResponse({'results': list(invoices_all_data )})
```

template

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/invoices/vindication_filter/",
    data: {
        vindication_type: vindication_type,
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
        //response['results'] is your invoices_all_data
}
});
```

Comment: django view cant return query set, response should be httpresponse.

Comment: @Kostas Charitidis i have already try this, but for now it is not working. I put the data from response by 
$('#data').html(response); . It is correct?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede correct I didn't though even see the type of data, so he can parse them to json to handle them in ajax

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi use a jsonresponse and use the debugger in your browser to see the results.

Comment: @Kostas Charitidis i get error on return JsonResponse: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user' in site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py